# My textarea on laravel doesn't give any value when update - laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

I need some advice. I make a view for editing a database that contains textarea form. Unfortunately, when I hit the save button it doesn't give any change to the database. What should I do?

Here's the form in infoupdate.blade.view:

```
<form action="{{ route('updateinfo') }}" method="POST">
            @method('PUT')
            @csrf
            <div class="intro-y box p-5">
                <div>
                    <div class="mt-3"> <label for="by" class="form-label">Oleh</label> <input name="by" id="by" type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ auth()->user()->username }}" readonly></div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div class="mt-3"> <label for="selectedTime" class="form-label">Waktu Pengumuman</label> <input name="selectedTime" id="selectedTime" type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ $infos->selectedTime }}" readonly></div>
                </div>
                <div class="mt-3">
                    <label class="pb-8" for="contentInfo">Isi Pengumuman</label>
                    <textarea name="contentInfo" id="contentInfo" class="w-full border-2" rows="10" cols="100">{{ $infos->contentInfo }}</textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="text-right mt-5">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary w-24">Simpan</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Also the update function in DBIController.php:

```
public function update(Request $request){
        $request->validate([
            'contentInfo' => 'required|min:16'
        ]);
        DB::table('infos')->where('id', $request->id)->update([
            'contentInfo' => $request->contentInfo
            ]);
        return redirect()->route('DBI')->with('message','Data Pengumuman Berhasil di Update');
    }
```

and the route for displaying the form and the route for updating database in web.php :

```
Route::get('/infoeditor/{id}',[DBIController::class, 'edit'])->middleware('admin')->name('infoeditor');
Route::put('/updateinfo',[DBIController::class,  'update'])->middleware('admin')->name('updateinfo');
```

Comment: add hidden field to form <input type="hidden" value="{{$infos->id}}" name="id"/>

Comment: `id` is missing in the form and which you are using in the query. You can add that in URL too as you have used in edit.

Comment: @JohnLobo like what?

Comment: @AradentaFareast add input filed like i mentioned inside form

Comment: @JohnLobo, Thankyou, it works as well

Answer (score 1):

on your update route, you need to add `/{id}`

`Route::put('/updateinfo/{id}',[DBIController::class,  'update'])->middleware('admin')->name('updateinfo');`

Then, in your controller method, you will add $id as parameter

```
public function update(Request $request, int $id)
{
    $request->validate([
        'contentInfo' => 'required|min:16'
    ]);
    DB::table('infos')->where('id', $id)->update([
        'contentInfo' => $request->contentInfo
    ]);
    return redirect()->route('DBI')->with('message','Data Pengumuman Berhasil di Update');
}
```

And in your view, you update the action url with $id

`<form action="{{ route('updateinfo', ['id' => $infos->id]) }}" method="POST">`

Comment: upvoted your answers :)

Comment: Thankyou @Dyos, It works!